# Python count elements in dictionary comprehension when count is above a threshold

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary-comprehension

I want to populate a dictionary with the counts of various items in a list, but only when the count exceeds a certain number. (This is in Python 2.7)

For example:

`x = [2,3,4,2,3,5,6]` if I only want numbers that appear twice or more, I would want only
`d = {2: 2, 3: 2}` as an output.

I wanted to do this with a dictionary comprehension, for example

```
{(num if x.count(num) >= 2): x.count(num) for num in x}
```

But this throws an "invalid syntax" error, and it seems I need to set some default key, which means some key I don't want being added to the dictionary which I then have to remove.

What I'm doing now is in two lines:

```
d = {(num if x.count(num) >= 2 else None): x.count(num) for num in x}

d.pop(None, None)
```

But is there a way to do it in one, or to do the dictionary comprehension with an if statement without actually adding any default key for the else statement?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count each items in `x`, the use a dictionary comprehension to pull those values where the count is greater than or equal to your threshold (e.g. 2).

```
from collections import Counter

x = [2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6]
threshold = 2
c = Counter(x)
d = {k: v for k, v in c.iteritems() if v >= threshold}
>>> d
{2: 2, 3: 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

That works:

```
{ i: x.count(i) for i in x if x.count(i) >= 2}
```

The `if` part must be after the `for`, not before, that's why you get the syntax error.

To avoid counting elements twice, and without any extra import, you could also use two nested comprehensions (actually the inner one is a generator to avoid iterating the full list twice) :

```
>>> { j: n for j, n in ((i, x.count(i)) for i in x) if n >= 2}
{2: 2, 3: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The test in your expression: `(num if x.count(num) >= 2 else None)` comes too late: you already instructed the dict comp to issue a value. You have to filter it out beforehand.

just move the condition from ternary to the filter part of the comprehension:

```
x = [2,3,4,2,3,5,6]
d = {num: x.count(num) for num in x if x.count(num) >= 2}
```

that said, this method isn't very effective, because it counts elements twice.

Filter a `Counter` instead:

```
import collections

d = {num:count for num,count in collections.Counter(x).items() if count>=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
a = [1,2,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,2,2,2]   
{n: a.count(n) for n in set(a) if a.count(n) >= 2}   
{2: 6, 4: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This should work:**

Input:

```
a = [2,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,4]
```

Code:

```py
x = { i : a.count(i) for i in a }

print(x)
```

Output:

```py
>>> {2: 4, 1: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question. The OP already know how to do that. Their question was "how to add condition "if count > 2"" to get only `{2:4, 1:3}`. And the way to do so within such a comprehension has already been given in another answer. When answering old question, be extra careful to add new information to what was already given.